# '[table.20121128]' in a larger, double-quoted string in bash is evaluating to '1' when I echo it

Tags: bash, shell

Here's a query string in a bash script that I wrote.

"SELECT day,xxx,yyy,zzz,if(count>$threshold,keyword,'_other') as keyword, sum(count) as searches
FROM
(SELECT
LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp*1000000)),10) as day,
xxx, yyy, zzz,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(actiondata,'wvq=([^&]*)') as keyword,
COUNT(*) as count
**FROM [table.$dir_prefix]**
WHERE product='myproduct'
AND LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp*1000000),10) = '$1'
AND REGEXP_MATCH(actiondata,'wvq=')
GROUP BY day,xxx, yyy,zzz,keyword
)
GROUP BY day,xxx,yyy,zzz, keyword

ORDER BY searches DESC;"

---

When I echo this string, the output is:

"SELECT day,xxx,yyy,zzz,if(count>50,keyword,'_other') as keyword, sum(count) as searches
FROM
(SELECT
LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp*1000000)),10) as day,
xxx, yyy, zzz,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(actiondata,'wvq=([^&]*)') as keyword,
COUNT(*) as count
**FROM 1**
WHERE product='myproduct'
AND LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp*1000000),10) = '2012-11-28'
AND REGEXP_MATCH(actiondata,'wvq=')
GROUP BY day,xxx, yyy,zzz,keyword
)
GROUP BY day,xxx,yyy,zzz, keyword

ORDER BY searches DESC;"

---

Isolating the string and echoing "[table.$dir_prefix]" outputs the expected string, [table.20121128]. Can anyone explain why this is being evaluated in the larger string as '1'?

Escaping the square brackets (\[table.$dir_prefix\]) does not solve the problem.

**More details:** 
$dir_prefix and $threshold are set to **20121128** and **50**, respectively.
The string is being set like so:

```
to_echo=\
"SELECT day,xxx,yyy,zzz,if(count>$threshold,keyword,'_other') as keyword, sum(count) as searches FROM (SELECT LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp*1000000)),10) as day, xxx, yyy, zzz, REGEXP_EXTRACT(actiondata,'wvq=([^&])') as keyword, COUNT() as count FROM [table.$dir_prefix] WHERE product='myproduct' AND LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp*1000000),10) = '$1' AND REGEXP_MATCH(actiondata,'wvq=') GROUP BY day,xxx, yyy,zzz,keyword ) GROUP BY day,xxx,yyy,zzz, keyword

ORDER BY searches DESC;"
```

---

**Update 2**

The script only has the issue on this specific server (running Ubuntu). My other server (running Redhat) does not have the problem and outputs what's expected. It must be something configuration related. I can work around it but I *really* just want to know what's behind this.

Here's the exact script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_prefix=`date --date "$1" +%Y%m%d`;
threshold=$2;

query="SELECT day,xxx,yyy,zzz,if(count>$threshold,keyword,'_other') as keyword, sum(count) as searches FROM (SELECT LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp*1000000)),10) as day, xxx, yyy, zzz, REGEXP_EXTRACT(actiondata,'wvq=([^&])') as keyword, COUNT() as count FROM [table.$dir_prefix] WHERE product='myproduct' AND LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp*1000000),10) = '$1' AND REGEXP_MATCH(actiondata,'wvq=') GROUP BY day,xxx, yyy,zzz,keyword ) GROUP BY day,xxx,yyy,zzz, keyword

ORDER BY searches DESC;"

echo $query;
```

**Solution: More Info**

Here's a good write-up that goes into detail on preventing globbing when you don't want it. I went with the set -f option.

http://blog.edwards-research.com/2011/05/preventing-globbing/

Comment: Can you clarify how you're setting the string, and what dir_prefix is set to?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added more details.

Comment: Works as expected for me: `dir_prefix=20121128;threshold=50;to_echo=...;echo $to_echo` prints `table.20121128` in the place of alleged trouble. Something else must be going on.

Comment: are you using `eval` on your string? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter No I'm not. I've posted the exact script above along with some more details. It seems to only occur on one of my servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file named `1` in the current directory, and it's being globbed.

```
$ touch 1
$ echo [foo.123]
1
$ echo [foo.234]
[foo.234]
```

Comment: Wow, you are correct. I'm not sure where that file came from. Good catch.

Comment: The fix is not to remove the file though, it's to inhibit globbing.

Comment: I think it would make more sense for that to be included in your answer but I added some more info to my post.